# .net Core 2 Include Then Include Does Not Work

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I made a project with .net core 2 and used entity framework. I have three models which are file, label and klass

```
public class Label
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double TOP_LOC { get; set; }
    public double LEFT_LOC { get; set; }
    public double RIGHT_LOC { get; set; }
    public double BOTTOM_LOC { get; set; }

    public File FILE { get; set; }

    public Klass KLASS { get; set; }
}


public class Klass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string KLASS_NAME { get; set; }

    public List<Label> LABEL { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FILE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public bool FINAL_IS_VALID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CREATED_DATE { get; set; }
    public int REQ_COUNT { get; set; }
    public int CUR_COUNT { get; set; }
    public double REQ_PER_CENT { get; set; }
    public double CUR_PER_CENT { get; set; }

    public User USER { get; set; }

    public List<Validation> VALIDATION { get; set; }

    public List<Label> LABEL { get; set; }
}
```

Here to get the list of Files i am using

```
Models.File toBeValidated = DbObjects.FILE.Include(x => x.LABEL).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
```

in this variation toBeValidated.FILE.LABEL.KLASS is null

when I want to include the KLASS too I use thenInclude(a=>a. ...) however nothing comes.

What should I do what I am doing wrong if you can help me I appriciate that.

Comment: Intellisense just doesn't pop up, but try to type it anyway. It happens with collections.

Comment: It worked thank you. Please write it as answer so i can mark as solved.

Comment: Instead of .ThenInclude you can also just do .Include(x => x.LABEL.KLASS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense doesn't come up and somehow this happens when you use it on collections. Type it out and it should just compile and work:

```
Models.File toBeValidated = DbObjects.FILE.Include(fil => fil.LABEL)
                                          .ThenInclude(lbl => lbl.KLASS)
                                          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
```